# Link not completely clickable

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

A part of a link is not clickable. Nothing is on top of it. You can even select the text but not being treated as a link. I checked in Firefox and it's working properly. Just in Chrome.

I attached a .gif to show what's happening.

[[image: Problem with anchor tag]

I wrapped an anchor tag with `h1` tag. The whole text **SHOULD BE** treated as a link. As the gif shows, the text is selected, which means nothing is on top of the link and yet, Chrome doesn't treat the whole text as a link.

Any idea what's happening?

Here's the html of that text

```html
<h1 class="post-title">
  <a href="#">Vix sumo exerci, mel aeterno feugiat intellegam cu</a>
</h1>
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the [link](http://paologallardo.com/project-samples/celeste-html-template/) of this project

Comment: That is very odd, which version of chrome are you using? Because it works fine for me on chrome.

Comment: I am using 48.0.2564.116.
Chrome tells me that it's up to date.

Comment: Maybe check the `z-index` try in developer tool.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the code you posted. It must be some other factor.

Comment: @mmativ Already checked. but nothing is on top of it.

Comment: @user2586153 you need to show the relevant code, there is another thing messing with this `a`

Comment: @5parc +1 it's working for me.

Comment: try to put an actual code just copy and paste at `fiddle` or give a link of the website so we can inspect it.

Comment: There must be something else at play here. Out of interest, have you tried setting the link to `display: block;` to see if that changes the behaviour?

Comment: I edited the question and added a link to the project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to give `display:block` to your `a` because `a` by default is a inline element and for some reason when you set `font-size:15px` to `a` and `line-height:12px` in `h1` parent it won't recognize the first part of `a` in Chrome

Comment: Works now and thanks for the explanation of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes it for me.

```
.post-title a {
    position: relative;
}
```

Very strange, though.